# Spring boot RedisTemplate configuration cluster write object is very slow, if the stand-alone is very fast, why?

Tags: spring-boot, redis

Spring boot RedisTemplate configuration cluster write object is very slow, if the stand-alone is very fast, why?

What do I need to configure?

Comment: My application.yml configuration 

spring:
  redis:
    cluster:
      nodes:
        - 192.168.156.161:7000
        - 192.168.156.161:7001
        - 192.168.156.161:7002
        - 192.168.156.161:7003
        - 192.168.156.161:7004
        - 192.168.156.161:7005
      max-redirects: 50

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you set max-redirects=50, this is too large a number in practice. Typically 5 is fairly enough. If your Redis client actually redirects like 30+ or 40+, it's not strange your write being slow. Set it to 5, and run again for cluster mode. If it redirects too many times, a error message like `Too Many Cluster Redirection Exception` shall be popped up in your log. Then it may suggest a connection problem to one of those redis instance.

FYI,  Spring boot RedisTemplate uses Jedis under-hood.